# newVoiceState.channel.(anything) does not exist discord.js V13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have this bit of code `console.log(newVoiceState.channel)`
inside `client.on("voiceStateUpdate", async (oldVoiceState, newVoiceState) => {` that returns:

```json
<ref *2> VoiceChannel {
  type: 'GUILD_VOICE',
  guild: <ref *1> Guild {
    id: '927224001141538816',
    name: 'Test server bot',
    icon: null,
    features: [],
    commands: GuildApplicationCommandManager {
      permissions: [ApplicationCommandPermissionsManager],
      guild: [Circular *1]
    },
    members: GuildMemberManager { guild: [Circular *1] },
    channels: GuildChannelManager { guild: [Circular *1] },
    bans: GuildBanManager { guild: [Circular *1] },
    roles: RoleManager { guild: [Circular *1] },
    presences: PresenceManager {},
    voiceStates: VoiceStateManager { guild: [Circular *1] },
    stageInstances: StageInstanceManager { guild: [Circular *1] },
    invites: GuildInviteManager { guild: [Circular *1] },
    scheduledEvents: GuildScheduledEventManager { guild: [Circular *1] },
    available: true,
    shardId: 0,
    splash: null,
    banner: null,
    description: null,
    verificationLevel: 'NONE',
    vanityURLCode: null,
    nsfwLevel: 'DEFAULT',
    discoverySplash: null,
    memberCount: 4,
    large: false,
    premiumProgressBarEnabled: false,
    applicationId: null,
    afkTimeout: 300,
    afkChannelId: null,
    systemChannelId: '927224001141538819',
    premiumTier: 'NONE',
    premiumSubscriptionCount: 0,
    explicitContentFilter: 'DISABLED',
    mfaLevel: 'NONE',
    joinedTimestamp: 1641463218689,
    defaultMessageNotifications: 'ALL_MESSAGES',
    systemChannelFlags: SystemChannelFlags { bitfield: 0 },
    maximumMembers: 250000,
    maximumPresences: null,
    approximateMemberCount: null,
    approximatePresenceCount: null,
    vanityURLUses: null,
    rulesChannelId: null,
    publicUpdatesChannelId: null,
    preferredLocale: 'en-US',
    ownerId: '291272018773671937',
    emojis: GuildEmojiManager { guild: [Circular *1] },
    stickers: GuildStickerManager { guild: [Circular *1] }
  },
  guildId: '927224001141538816',
  parentId: '927224001141538818',
  permissionOverwrites: PermissionOverwriteManager { channel: [Circular *2] },
  id: '927224001141538820',
  name: 'General',
  rawPosition: 0,
  rtcRegion: null,
  bitrate: 64000,
  userLimit: 0
}
```

But when I try `newVoiceState.channel.parentId`, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentId')
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\nigel\OneDrive\Software\Code\Discord-Bots\DijkdamRP\events\voiceStateUpdate.js:28:37)
    at Client.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at VoiceStateUpdate.handle (C:\Users\nigel\OneDrive\Software\Code\Discord-Bots\DijkdamRP\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\VoiceStateUpdate.js:38:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as VOICE_STATE_UPDATE] (C:\Users\nigel\OneDrive\Software\Code\Discord-Bots\DijkdamRP\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\VOICE_STATE_UPDATE.js:4:35)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\nigel\OneDrive\Software\Code\Discord-Bots\DijkdamRP\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:351:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\nigel\OneDrive\Software\Code\Discord-Bots\DijkdamRP\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\nigel\OneDrive\Software\Code\Discord-Bots\DijkdamRP\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\nigel\OneDrive\Software\Code\Discord-Bots\DijkdamRP\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:199:18)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\nigel\OneDrive\Software\Code\Discord-Bots\DijkdamRP\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:1098:20) Promise {
  <rejected> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentId')
      at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\nigel\OneDrive\Software\Code\Discord-Bots\DijkdamRP\events\voiceStateUpdate.js:28:37)
      at Client.emit (node:events:390:28)
      at VoiceStateUpdate.handle (C:\Users\nigel\OneDrive\Software\Code\Discord-Bots\DijkdamRP\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\VoiceStateUpdate.js:38:14)
      at Object.module.exports [as VOICE_STATE_UPDATE] (C:\Users\nigel\OneDrive\Software\Code\Discord-Bots\DijkdamRP\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\VOICE_STATE_UPDATE.js:4:35)
      at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\nigel\OneDrive\Software\Code\Discord-Bots\DijkdamRP\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:351:31)
      at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\nigel\OneDrive\Software\Code\Discord-Bots\DijkdamRP\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
      at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\nigel\OneDrive\Software\Code\Discord-Bots\DijkdamRP\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
      at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\nigel\OneDrive\Software\Code\Discord-Bots\DijkdamRP\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:199:18)
      at WebSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
      at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\nigel\OneDrive\Software\Code\Discord-Bots\DijkdamRP\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:1098:20)
}
```

It's the same for literally every other `channel.x` property. For example `channel.guildId` although seen very clearly in the other `console.log` is suddenly not there.

How is this possible and how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add some relevant code?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros I cant really add more code because console.log(newVoiceState.channel) is basicly the entire file exept for the modules.export part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`voiceStateUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-voiceStateUpdate) is emitted whenever a member changes their voice state. In some cases, e.g. when someone leaves a voice channel, `newVoiceState.channel` will be `null` and if you try to read a property of this, it will throw a `TypeError`.

You'll need to compare the [`voiceState`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/VoiceState)s before and after the update to figure out what triggered the `voiceStateUpdate` event. I've just added some code below with a few examples. The following code logs if someone joined/left/switched channels, or if there are other changes like muted/unmuted themselves, started sharing their screen, etc.:

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
  if (newState.channel && !oldState.channel)
    console.log(
      `${newState.member.displayName} has joined the voice channel "${newState.channel.name}"`
    );

  if (!newState.channel && oldState.channel)
    console.log(
      `${oldState.member.displayName} has left the voice channel "${oldState.channel.name}"`
    );

  if (newState.channel && oldState.channel) {
    if (newState.channel.id !== oldState.channel.id) {
      console.log(
        `${newState.member.displayName} has left the voice channel "${oldState.channel.name}" and joined "${newState.channel.name}"`
      );
    } else {
      console.log(
        `${newState.member.displayName} is still in the voice channel "${oldState.channel.name}" but there were some changes (e.g. muted/unmuted themselves, started sharing their screen, etc.)`
      );
    }
  }
});
```